# Update/upsert with bulkWrite not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having difficulty getting `Model.bulkWrite` to upsert my documents.  I haven't found anything in the documentation to suggest that this isn't possible (though, maybe I missed it).  Below is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
var opts = [];
for (var item of data){
    opts.push({
        updateOne: {
            filter: {"id": item.id},
            update: {"$setOnInsert": {
                    "id": item.id,
                    "name": item.name}
            }
        }
    })
};

Item.bulkWrite(
    opts,
    {upsert: true},
    function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        // do more stuff here
    }
);
```

I don't have any trouble running multiple update/upserts through a loop, but when I do that I lose access to a callback on when the operation is complete, so that doesn't work for me.  I've also tested the above code replacing the `updateOne` section with an `insertOne` section and it works with no problems.

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?  Is upsert not a valid option here?

Comment: `{upsert: true},` is an option of `updateOne`, not `bulkWrite`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Alex Blex, you were right on the money.  Just an oversight on my part, I guess.  For those interested this meant removing the `upsert` from the second section of code and changing the first section to:

```
var opts = [];
for (var item of data){
    opts.push({
        updateOne: {
            filter: {"id": item.id},
            update: {"$setOnInsert": {
                    "id": item.id,
                    "name": item.name}
            },
            upsert: true
        }
    })
};
```